# Quiero mostrar un array en un textArea en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy intentando que me salga en un textarea de un formulario todo el contenido de un array.

```
$aPuntos = [
    "punto01" =>[15, 8, "rojo", 1],
    "punto02" =>[100, 20, "negro", 2],
    "punto03" =>[200, 200, "amarillo", 3]
];
```

Intento colocarlo en un textArea asi:

```
<textarea name="puntos" cols="70" rows="10">
    <?php
        foreach($aPuntos as $clave => $valor){
            echo $clave ." tiene los siguientes valores " .$valor ."<br>".PHP_EOL;
        }
    ?>
</textarea>
```

Pero me muestra un tocho de código html que ni se de donde procede, solo quiero mostrar ese array en el textarea

Comment: Nos deberías mostrar esa *salida* que indicas

Comment: Podrías usar javascript para hacer lo que dices o usar las variables $_POST o $_GET para obtener el contenido que viaja. Pienso que hacerlo con javascript te sería más facil

Comment: Estoy estudiando PHP y no quiere nada de JavaScript, por eso es.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene tres problemas:

1. No estarías cerrando el bloque PHP con `?>` antes de pasar a la parte del `textarea`
2. **En el recorrido del `foreach`, cada `$valor` es a su vez un array. Podrías usar `implode()` para listar con un separador los valores que haya en cada `$valor`**.
3. Estarías cerrando el bloque `php` al final del `textarea` sin necesidad.

Puede que los errores 1 y 2 pierdan sentido si hay más código de por medio. Sin embargo, para evitar este tipo de situaciones te recomendaría que evites mezclar bloques PHP/HTML. Producen un código ilegible, complicado para depurar/analizar y es más fácil cometer errores. Se podría escribir todo en un bloque PHP concatenado, como se muestra al final.

### Código actual, corregido

```
aPuntos = [
    "punto01" =>[15, 8, "rojo", 1],
    "punto02" =>[100, 20, "negro", 2],
    "punto03" =>[200, 200, "amarillo", 3]
];

?>
<textarea name="puntos" cols="70" rows="10">
    <?php
        foreach($aPuntos as $clave => $valor){
            echo $clave ." tiene los siguientes valores: " .implode(", ",$valor) ."<br>".PHP_EOL;
        }
    ?>
</textarea>
```

### Código concatenando

```
<?php
    $aPuntos = [
        "punto01" =>[15, 8, "rojo", 1],
        "punto02" =>[100, 20, "negro", 2],
        "punto03" =>[200, 200, "amarillo", 3]
    ];
    $html="";
    $html.="<textarea name=\"puntos\" cols=\"70\" rows=\"10\">";
            foreach($aPuntos as $clave => $valor){
                $html.="$clave tiene los siguientes valores: " .implode(", ",$valor)."<br>".PHP_EOL;
            }
    $html.="</textarea>";
    echo $html;
?>
```

---

**Salida:**

En ambos casos, tendrás la salida correcta:

```html
<textarea name="puntos" cols="70" rows="10">
punto01 tiene los siguientes valores: 15, 8, rojo, 1<br>
punto02 tiene los siguientes valores: 100, 20, negro, 2<br>
punto03 tiene los siguientes valores: 200, 200, amarillo, 3<br>
</textarea>
```